# Pipeline to post item into storage service

Tags: python, asynchronous, scrapy, twisted, dropbox

I want a pipeline to async POST items to a storage service. I have the thought of using something like FilePipeline for this. FilePipeline comes with a lot of overhead, because it assumes I want to save files to disk, but here I just want to post the files to a storage API. However, it does have a method that yields Requests: `get_media_requests()`.

I currently get `FileException` failure, and I don't know how to eliminate the component that saves to disk. Is there a way to make this work nicely?

```
class StoragePipeline(FilePipeline):


    access_token = os.environ['access_token']

    def get_media_requests(self, item, info):

        filename = item['filename']


        headers = {
            'Authorization': f'Bearer {self.access_token}',
            'Dropbox-API-Arg': f'{{"path": "/{filename}"}}',
            'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
        }

        request = Request(
            method='POST',
            url='https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload',
            headers=headers,
            body=item['data'],

        )

        yield request


    def item_completed(self, results, item, info):

        return item
```

Comment: You can have a look at [Scrapy Book](https://www.packtpub.com/big-data-and-business-intelligence/learning-scrapy)'s samples, like [this async ElasticSearch pipeline](https://github.com/scalingexcellence/scrapybook/blob/5a6600abecb50e344b7aa6eaf03a181dbbbb08c0/ch09/properties/properties/pipelines/es.py).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can schedule scrapy requests in pipelines by exposing crawler and scheduling your request directly:

```
class MyPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self, crawler):
        self.crawler = crawler

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        return cls(crawler)

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        if item['some_extra_field']:  # check if we already did below
            return item
        req = scrapy.Request('some_url', self.check_deploy,
                             method='POST', meta={'item': item})
        self.crawler.engine.crawl(req, spider)
        return item

    def check_deploy(self, response):
        # if not 200 we might want to retry
        if response.status != 200: 
            return response.meta['item']
```